# Private Data in VMMap is very large on some machines

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, window, vmmap

I'm trying to debug a memory exhaustion issue for my native Win32 CPP app, so far i have found that on some machine when launched, app the memory usage is very high from the beginning and VMMap is showing around 300MB as private data (Committed) and heap is very small.
[image]
On machine where this issue is not reproducible, same private data would be size of 1-2MB only. While using heap profiling in MSVS, I can't see these private data section and heap remains small.
Could this be due to some machine configuration? I've checked that application verifier is not attached in the affected machine.
Any Suggestions on how to further debug this?

Comment: `Private Data (Committed)` is basically just... the heap. Windows has its own heap system (` HeapAlloc`) which `new` doesn't necessarily use. I would guess that only Windows's heap system would show up as `Heap`, not any other heap. Especially if you allocate a *large* piece of memory.

Comment: It was due to Pageheap being enabled on few systems.

Answer (score 1):

It was due to PageHeap being enabled for process (in some scenarios it could be due to application verifier as well).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).